# 4x4 2004 Ford Explorer Sport-trac transmission

Tags: ford, transmission, explorer, 4wd, replacements

We're replacing the transmission and wondering if we should include the short section (8-10" in length) ahead of the transfer case, or not, or should we replace the transfer case while we're at it?

We'll be pulling the replacement parts from a u-pick yard so we're looking for the most expeditious path without having to pay for the transfer case if we don't need it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure what you mean by "the section ahead of the transfer case" ... to me that means the transmission. Could you please explain it better? Edit your question and include the information ... Thanks!

Comment: There is a short section 8-10" in length between the transmission and transfer case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're talking about is the support which goes between the transmission and transfer case, then no, that does not need to be replaced. It is a solid piece and should be subjected to no wear. You will want to replace any gaskets or gasket material which goes between them, though. Since you've got the whole thing out, it's a good time to reseal these.